# Maven - Could not resolve dependencies for project X

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, maven, war

I'm trying to make a webservice and pack this into a .war file. 
Everything worked fine, untill i made some edits to the pom. After a few CTRL+Z's i can't get it back the way is was..

My current (not working pom) gives the following error:

*Failed to collect dependencies at com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.8*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.gis</groupId>
<artifactId>com.gis</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src.com.gis</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.gis</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have added the following jars to my Build Path:

- java-json.jar
- javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
- jersey-bundle-1.8.jar
- jersey-server.jar

Can anyone give me a hint to make this work properly again?

**EDIT: Removing .jars and closing proxy did the trick.
Unfortunatly, the next error is coming in:**

*SEVERE: Servlet [jersey-servlet] in web application [/com.gis] threw load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer*

Any hints anyone?

Comment: Did you try right click project Maven -> Update dependencies

Comment: Why are you using both maven dependency and direct jars in class?

Comment: You can remove the web.xml, has nothing to do with it. Remove manually added jars. Are you behind a fw or proxy?

Comment: I tried Update Project, but that didn't work.
Removed .jars and closed my proxy, clean install worked was successfull!

Comment: Hmm, next error is coming in. Have seen this one multiple times yesterday when i tried solving the issue above:

{SEVERE: Servlet [jersey-servlet] in web application [/com.gis] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer}

Any hints anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:Add jersey-server dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: Rightclick on project > Build with dependencies

Comment: I do not have that option. Tried Update Project, but that didn't work.
Removed .jars and closed my proxy did the trick! :)